# Apache serve only specific files, forward the others

Tags: networking, apache-http-server

I have the following situation here:

We use apache combined with an in-house server generating dynamic content, where apache is forwarding all requests coming in to the site, to the in-house server, via the following settings:

```
ProxyPass "/" http://127.0.0.1:8180/
ProxyPassReverse "/" http://127.0.0.1:8180/
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

On its turn the inhouse server generates content and sends this data back to apache which sends it to the browser.

The in-house server also takes care of serving static files, by reading them, setting proper content type and sending the reply back to apache.

Now, the question: I would like apache to serve some files which never change (such as logo, some images, static javascript, etc...) without ever forwarding them to the inhouse server (speed considerations). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass

Something like this should do it:

```
DocumentRoot /path/to/files/
<Directory /path/to/files/>
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
ProxyPass /static !

ProxyPass "/" http://127.0.0.1:8180/
ProxyPassReverse "/" http://127.0.0.1:8180/
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

This should serve all the files in `/path/to/files/static` locally instead of proxying them.